# jq, getting an unknown parent node after finding it with one of its children value

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I have a complex (at least for me) issue with jq, and this structure :

```json
{
  "os": {
    "ubuntu": {
      "16.04": {
        "codename": "xenial",
        "bootstrap": "preseed",
        "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
        "iso_name": "ubuntu-16.04.7-server-amd64.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "9bb30a2ea6466b0c02aacfa96f6e3516",
      },
      "18.04": {
        "codename": "bionic",
        "bootstrap": "preseed",
        "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
        "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "34416ff83179728d54583bf3f18d42d2",
        "arm": {
          "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.5-server-arm64.iso",
          "iso_checksum": "5056eaf87425b550376e6733b05de6e9"
        }
      }
    },
    "rhel": {
      "7.4": {
        "codename": "maipo",
        "bootstrap": "kickstart",
        "guest_type": "rhel7_64Guest",
        "iso_name": "rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-boot.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "94ad0929b79b5d13b33acafc8da8d364",
      },
      "7.6": {
        "codename": "maipo",
        "bootstrap": "kickstart",
        "guest_type": "rhel7_64Guest",
        "iso_name": "rhel-server-7.6-x86_64-boot.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "4a611d2bbfa6912eada91096af14ec84",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the "ubuntu" node content by searching it with "18.04", without knowing the "ubuntu" node key name.
So if i search the children node named "7.4", it should identify its parent as "rhel" and returns it.

Basically, with an os version, i should get the os name, but i have no way of knowing the os name beforehand.

I tried a few commands (didn't keep them sorry), with the help of this cheatsheet, without luck :
https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4

It is even possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: As i said, i didn't keep them. Tried on wsl and closed the session without capturing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the "ubuntu" node content

You can use `.[]` to get all nodes' contents, and `has` to check for their keys:

```bash
jq '.os[] | select(has("18.04"))'
```

```json
{
  "16.04": {
    "codename": "xenial",
    "bootstrap": "preseed",
    "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
    "iso_name": "ubuntu-16.04.7-server-amd64.iso",
    "iso_checksum": "9bb30a2ea6466b0c02aacfa96f6e3516"
  },
  "18.04": {
    "codename": "bionic",
    "bootstrap": "preseed",
    "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
    "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso",
    "iso_checksum": "34416ff83179728d54583bf3f18d42d2",
    "arm": {
      "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.5-server-arm64.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "5056eaf87425b550376e6733b05de6e9"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jvvqPgJeH6s)

If you want the object with the "ubuntu" field included, update `|=` the nodes:

```bash
jq '.os | .[] |= select(has("18.04"))'
```

```json
{
  "ubuntu": {
    "16.04": {
      "codename": "xenial",
      "bootstrap": "preseed",
      "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
      "iso_name": "ubuntu-16.04.7-server-amd64.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "9bb30a2ea6466b0c02aacfa96f6e3516"
    },
    "18.04": {
      "codename": "bionic",
      "bootstrap": "preseed",
      "guest_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
      "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "34416ff83179728d54583bf3f18d42d2",
      "arm": {
        "iso_name": "ubuntu-18.04.5-server-arm64.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "5056eaf87425b550376e6733b05de6e9"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8NOFbNi_Ze0)

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, with an os version, i should get the os name, but i have no way of knowing the os name beforehand.

You can use [`to_entires()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) with [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) and [`has()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has(key)) to filter those which nested object contains the desired key: `select(.value | has("18.04"))`.

Then return the parent's key to get the OS name (`.key`):

```
.os | to_entries[] | select(.value | has("18.04")).key
// "ubuntu"

.os | to_entries[] | select(.value | has("7.6")).key
// "rhel"
```

---

[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TS1RFpaszZv)

Comment: Works too thanks, but it displays the parent name (without .key at the end) as a key instead of a parent.
Interesting though.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. What needs to be changed?

Comment: Nothing, but i don't need only the os name but the whole block, so if use your code and remove the ".key" at the end, i don't exactly get what I need, see here :
https://jqplay.org/s/xDjY5785GIl

Sure, i could do another run with jq to get the whole block now that i know the os name, but it's better in one go.

I need to have ubuntu has a parent and not as a key with the result as a value.
@pmf second solution is exactly what i need.

Comment: @Guillaume Starting from here (with `.key` removed), you could make it an array and transform it back to an object using `from_entries` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ODJGC4Y0Krj) (which is a pattern that can be shortened to `with_entries` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RVdx3dn8Mqz) as `[.[] |…]` is just a `map`). But using a `*_entries` pattern without accessing `.key` practically serves no purpose, so you could just use the mapping (which for objects is called `map_values`) and drop the `.value` reference [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Qb5F7N8a3GX), which then is what I did (as `.[] |=` maps values).

Comment: It seems there is many ways to obtain the desired result, thanks for the explanation.